# Filter Match Function in Excel returns text field in all Asterisks

Tags: excel, filter, match

I am running this simple filter in a datasheet I am working with

```
=FILTER(Data!A2:BH25001,ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!BH2:BH25001,Keywords!A2:A5,0)))
```

It works fine all except for that fact that the data I am sorting today has a comment column that contains anywhere from 5 to 50 characters and for some reason, despite all other cell values pulling properly, every single Comment (BH2:B25001) shows up as some random number of Asterisks instead of the actual text in my filter. Same issue if I use Xmatch.

I have tried using wildcard Search which does show the text but when I do that I can only filter by ONE criteria as when I choose a table
I only get one result (similar to Vlookup) and I need to search for a list of 4 keywords to pull from that specific comments column. Any thoughts?

Edit:
So to make this easier to understand and to mitigate any issues with formatting I replaced the text in the message field with the Lyrics to 'Mary had a Little Lamb' and 'There was an old lady who swallowed a fly.'
Ran the same filter Looking for Words Mary, Fly, Spider and Bird.

[![Result][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtF5m.jpg

[![Raw Data][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFyBU.png

[![Keywords][3]][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOEPx.png

Comment: Your output is returning Asterix ? Have you tried checking is there any custom masking or something like that sort of ? Also you dont show any screenshots so we could see what is happening behind the screen

Comment: I wish it were that easy. It comes on an export from another tool in csv format, i copy the data and paste values only from that sheet to this one to avoid such issues. The filters just dont pull anything but asterisks from the one column unless I only use one word to filter with. Its so strange.

Comment: Is it possible there are some merged cells? Post a few examples of some values that are not behaving as you'd expect. Also, make sure the format in the column isn't something weird.

Comment: You must edit your question and provide some details of your data, along with a screenshot, and the screenshot of required result as well.

Comment: Updated and added screenshots. I cannot share the actual data I am working with but I did start with a new list, I built manually, no merging, special characters etc...